# Is there any way to extract data from #Prompt_assignment# variable in automation anywhere?

Tags: dll, bots, rpa, automationanywhere

There is a task to call DLL file and get output to the promptassignment variable in automation anywhere. That DLL returns the object (with student name and age). Is there any way to extract that students name and age from Promptassignmet variable without calling another DLL? Thnak you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you would want it to work, no.

Keep in mind that AA is by no means `Object oriented`. Hence, the parsing of the returned object needs to be done either in the dll itself (if you have access to its source code) or by AA's `Before-After` String operation.

Note that the latter is only viable when the returned Student object is not hashed, e.g. "Obj#12f837g", but has a `ToString()` format, e.g. "{student:{name:Foo, age:12}}".

In the former approach, instead of returning the Student object, you could return `student.name + ";" + student.age;` for example.

If neither of the 2 options listed above are viable for you, you can try creating a `metabot` via the Metabot Designer in the AAE Client. You can attach the dll and check if you can call its methods individually. The goal would be to find a `Getter` method for both 'name' and 'age'.

If all else fails, yes, you'll need to either run another dll which would serve your purpose, or create the dll yourself (this sounds like a fairly easy dll, but I could be wrong of course).

Hopefully one of the above will help you or at least guide you on finding your own solution.

Comment: Thank You Roel, yea I solved that matter by accessing Class library and I implemented sperated methods to return extracted details from the object. no other way to do that as you say. thanks